# What is the C++ equivalent of this Perl code that uses sprintf?

Tags: c++, perl, printf

I need to do mimic the functionality of the following Perl code

```
if($file =~ /^([^_]+)_([^_]+)_MA_(\d{4})(\d\d)(\d\d)_(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)\.MA$/) {
  my ($radar, $beam, $year, $month, $day, $hour, $min, $sec) =
      ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8);
  my $file_ts = sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d",
      $year, $month, $day, $hour, $min, $sec);

  # ...
}
```

in C++. Which function do I use for it?

Comment: `sprintf` in Perl is an implementation of the C call. I'm pretty sure you can do it in C++ as well.

Comment: mimicking that `sprintf` call is easy.  mimicking the `if` statement is... harder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same as in Perl:

```
char file_ts[1000];

snprintf(file_ts, "%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", year, month, day, hour, min, sec);
```

Answer (score 9):

Well, there's always the option of using `sprintf`:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/

or you can use `stringstream`, as the more C++-ish alternative.